# Would this constitute as a proper thesis?

Tags: grammar

> That’s why society, specifically college literature courses, should
>   include religious references in their texts because religious
>   references have wisdom, they promote intellectual curiosity, and
>   they’re full of applicable knowledge which is conducive to a college
>   learning environment for college students.

Would that constitute as a proper and correct thesis? I don't even know if it's formatted correctly and I need help. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is neither a proofreading service nor a writers workshop, though if you can identify a specific question about grammar or usage, we may be able to help. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how our site operates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a thesis idea service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to justify the use of "they" after a comma that closes what is already a full sentence. 

The assumption of anyone reading an argumentative paper is that the writer is making a claim, so you don't need to include "that's why" at the beginning.

Here is what I've changed:

> Religious texts promote intellectual curiosity, provide universally applicable knowledge, and should be included in college literature curricula.